# Is it ok to build an entire site with Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm creating a new site in Wordpress and found out this plugin is very powerfull and ended up creating customs fields for almost every part of the website, I've even placed WYSIWYG editors instead of built in ones because it's easier for me to code my templates.

Is it ok to build an entire site with Advanced Custom Fields or it may become an issue in the future?
Since the webpage is based on static products data, WP or plugins updates will rarely be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Is it ok to build an entire site with Advanced Custom Fields
```

#### IMO

It is "ok" to build an entire site with a plugin, but would I recommend it? probably not.

The only reason is because you never know what might happen to your site, if you install a "bad" plugin that breaks ACF plugin.

Or let say for some odd reason they stop providing support for ACF or updating it for whatever reason.
I've seen a lot of apps that have a good support system die out or get bought up by conglomerate companies and they stop public development and support.

```
 WP or plugins updates will rarely be needed.
```

Regardless you should keep updating your wordpress to current versions, you never know about a security exploits people find, wordpress core dev push out new versions to battle those exploits.

This can apply to plugins as well.

#### Personally

I like to build things myself without the reliance on plugins in general.

That way I only have the tools that I need, instead of extras that a plugin may come with.

Sometimes a few lines of code can go a long way instead of depending on plugins that may have thousands of lines of code.

Let alone wordpress has a lot of native options baked in that you can rely on or extend as opposed to relying heavily on ACF or any other plugin.

Comment: Very good answer, still a matter of points of view. I'll still use the plugin as intended, mostly because the client gave us very little time to develop his site, but it's good to know why it might not be a good idea. Thanks!